# How to visualize parts in parts?

Tags: info-visualisation, charts, graphs, infographic

I'm looking for a way to visualize parts of parts,

For example, I have a lot of pets and I want to show how many of each kind of pets are boys vs. girls .

I have:

Dogs, 5 female and 5 male

Fish, 2 male

Cats, 4 female and 1 male

Birds, 2 female and 6 male

and so on....

Any suggestions?

It will be possible to make the graph interactive, like clicking on a specific segment to see any further details. Although, I still want to give the user an overview of all pets and how many are boys/girls.

It is not important to show the total number of each pet. Also, it is not necessary to show all in *one* graph, it could be several if you see any point in that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A double bar graph sounds like the best chart type given your specifications that the chart must display the male/female split of each pet, and that the total number of each pet does not matter.

example:
[image: double bar graph]

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/) for interactive charts. Since the main functionality you wanted was interactivity here is a pretty standard chart.

[live demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/V9H5BSVQ)

[image]

You also mentioned the ability to click and get more information. This is possible using [drilldown](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/chart/#!drilldown-bar-chart) charts, but your post doesn't have enough information to make a demo relevant to your initial specifications. If you provide me some additional details you would have when "drilling" down, I would be more than happy to make that for you.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion could be to use what is a concept popularised by Edward Tufte known as '[small multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_multiple)' or a 'multiple chart' type. It is essentially tiling multiple charts of the same type so that you can get an overview of the distribution/patterns while still having a clear enough individual view to work how where you want to drill into for more details.

An example that might suit your purpose using a 'multiple pie chart' from a Microsoft Office Tutorial on the [topic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Tutorial-Create-Amazing-Power-View-Reports-Part-2-361b1fca-4429-42a2-94a2-e4d5f3e7d170):

[image]

But to make it more user friendly, you might want to use icons instead of labels to represent each type of pet. Not surprisingly (and just so I am not biased towards a particular vendor/solution) Tableau also has this [feature](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/getstarted_buildmanual_ex3nested.html) built into its offering.

Answer (score 1):

If the comparison between total dogs, cats etc is importand you may use the following graph style:

[image]

Comment: This would be better suited if the critical piece of information was the total number of each Animal type. The original question stated that the total number was not important, but indicating the male/female counts for each pet was very important. That information is not particularly clear from a stacked bar graph because the y-axis will not provide a count for the male/female split.